# Struggling to set values of subclass (down casting?)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift & swift UI so forgive me if there is an obvious answer to this question.

I'm trying to dynamically change the information within a view based on certain questions. Different types of questions require different responses. How do I properly  down cast the Question object in QuestionResponseView as the proper subclass so that I can set the user's responses to the questions?

(Note: I still need to finish some design elements. I'm trying to solve this functionality issue before moving forward)

Thank you!

The Question object and it's subclasses:

```
struct Questions {
    static let CheckinQuestions : [Question] = [
        ValueResponseQuestion(questionText: "How many hours of sleep did you get last night?", initialValue: 6, maxValue: 12),
        TextResponseQuestion(questionText: "What is taking up most of your headspace today?", responseText: "Family, Work, Children, Argument with friend"),
        TextResponseQuestion(questionText: "What do you feel you need in this moment? What is missing?", responseText: "Friendship, Money, Peace, Exercise"),
        ValueResponseQuestion(questionText: "What is your stress level currently at?", initialValue: 50, maxValue: 100)
    ]
    static var GroundingQuestions : [Question] = [
        //TODO: (later)
    ]

}

class Question : ObservableObject {
    var questionText : String
    
    init(questionText: String) {
        self.questionText = questionText
    }
}

class ValueResponseQuestion : Question {
    
    var responseValue : Double
    var minValue : Double = 0
    var maxVal : Double
    
    init(questionText: String, initialValue: Double, maxValue: Double) {
        responseValue = initialValue
        maxVal = maxValue
        super.init(questionText: questionText)
    }
}

class TextResponseQuestion : Question {
    var responseText : String
    
    init(questionText: String, responseText: String){
        self.responseText = responseText
        super.init(questionText: questionText)
    }   
}
```

The view where the user answers the questions from the array in the previous file, and the answer's are supposed to be recorded when the button is pressed.

```
struct QuestionResponseView: View {
    
    /** Variable that tracks the current question from the array of questions */
    @State var questionNum : Int = 0
    /** The current question (starting at the beginning of the array) */
    @State var question : Question = Questions.CheckinQuestions[0]
    
    //TODO: Do I need this, or can I simply save this value in the ValueResponseQuestion class?
    /** The variable used to track value responses from slider  */
    @State private var responseVal: Double = 6.0
    
    //TODO: Do I need this, or can I simply save this value in the TextResponseQuestion class?
    /** The variable used to track text responses from the text box */
    @State private var responseText: String = "Placeholder"
    
    /** The progress bar at the top of the page that tracks the current question */
    private var progressView : RoundedProgressBar
    
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        
        progressView = RoundedProgressBar(progressVal: 1)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text("Let's start...").font(.title)
            
            Spacer()
            progressView
            Spacer()
            
            VStack{
                Text("\(question.questionText)").padding()
                
                if question is ValueResponseQuestion {
                    
                    //TODO: Set value response
                    //How can I get/set this from the question object?
                    Slider(value: $responseVal, in: 0...12).padding()
                    
                } else if question is TextResponseQuestion {
                    //How can I get/set this from the question object?
                    TextEditor(text: $responseText).background(.thickMaterial).frame(width: 285, height: 250).cornerRadius(20).padding()
                    
                }
                
            }.frame(width: 340, height: 490, alignment: .center).overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40).stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 3))
            
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button{
                //Record responses and change the question
                
                //How do I downcast question to TextResponseQuestion so that I can access and set this value?
                question.questionResponseText = responseText
                
                print(question)
                
                
                responseText = "Placeholder"
                
                questionNum += 1
                
                if questionNum < Questions.CheckinQuestions.endIndex {
                    question = Questions.CheckinQuestions[questionNum]
                }
                
                else {
                    
                }
                
                progressView.increaseProgress()
                
            } label: {
                Text("Next Question").foregroundColor(.white).padding()
            }.frame(width: 150, height: 30).background(Color(red: 0.376, green: 0.4, blue: 0.816)).cornerRadius(3)
        }
    }
}

struct QuestionResponseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        QuestionResponseView()
    }
}
```

Image of view just for kicks:
[image: Image of view just for kicks:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes that are `ObservableObject` need to be observed so you can see/make changes. When you pass the initial value for the `@ObservedObject` you can cast it to the specific type.

There are comments in the code too.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct QuestionResponseView: View {
    
    @State var repository: QuestionRepository = QuestionRepository()
    @State var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            if currentQuestionIndex == 0{
            Text("Let's start...").font(.title)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("\(currentQuestionIndex + 1)/\(repository.checkInQuestion.count)")
            ProgressView("progress", value: Double(currentQuestionIndex)/Double(repository.checkInQuestion.count))
            Spacer()
            TabView(selection: $currentQuestionIndex){
                ForEach($repository.checkInQuestion){ $question in
                    ScrollView{
                        VStack{
                            Text("\(question.questionText)").padding()
                            
                            if question is ValueResponseQuestion {
                                //Once you check it you can cast it
                                ValueResponseQuestionView(question: question as! ValueResponseQuestion)
                            } else if question is TextResponseQuestion {
                                //Once you check it you can cast it
                                TextResponseQuestionView(question: question as! TextResponseQuestion)
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                        }.frame(width: 340, height: 490, alignment: .center).overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40).stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 3))
                        
                        
                        Spacer()
                        Button( action: {
                            if currentQuestionIndex >= repository.checkInQuestion.count - 1 {
                                currentQuestionIndex = 0
                            }else{
                                currentQuestionIndex += 1
                            }
                        }, label:{
                            Text("Next Question").foregroundColor(.white)
                        })
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 30)
                        .background(Color(red: 0.376, green: 0.4, blue: 0.816)).cornerRadius(3)
                    }.tag(repository.checkInQuestion.firstIndex(where: {
                        $0 == question
                    })!)
                }
            }.tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
}
struct ValueResponseQuestionView: View{
    //ObservableObjects have to be observed so you see changes
    @ObservedObject var question: ValueResponseQuestion
    var body: some View{
        //TODO: Set value response
        //How can I get/set this from the question object?
        Slider(value: $question.responseValue, in: question.minValue...question.maxVal).padding()
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct TextResponseQuestionView: View{
    //ObservableObjects have to be observed so you see changes
    @ObservedObject var question: TextResponseQuestion
    var body: some View{
        TextEditor(text: $question.responseText).background(.thickMaterial).frame(width: 285, height: 250).cornerRadius(20).padding()
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct QuestionResponseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        QuestionResponseView()
    }
}
struct QuestionRepository {
    //static let == does not change
    var checkInQuestion : [Question] = [
        ValueResponseQuestion(questionText: "How many hours of sleep did you get last night?", initialValue: 6, maxValue: 12),
        TextResponseQuestion(questionText: "What is taking up most of your headspace today?", responseText: "Family, Work, Children, Argument with friend"),
        TextResponseQuestion(questionText: "What do you feel you need in this moment? What is missing?", responseText: "Friendship, Money, Peace, Exercise"),
        ValueResponseQuestion(questionText: "What is your stress level currently at?", initialValue: 50, maxValue: 100)
    ]
    var GroundingQuestions : [Question] = [
        //TODO: (later)
    ]

}

class Question : ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Question, rhs: Question) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(questionText)
    }
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var questionText : String
    
    init(questionText: String) {
        self.questionText = questionText
    }
}

class ValueResponseQuestion : Question {
    
    @Published var responseValue : Double
    @Published var minValue : Double = 0
    @Published var maxVal : Double
    
    init(questionText: String, initialValue: Double, maxValue: Double) {
        responseValue = initialValue
        maxVal = maxValue
        super.init(questionText: questionText)
    }
}

class TextResponseQuestion : Question {
    @Published var responseText : String
    
    init(questionText: String, responseText: String){
        self.responseText = responseText
        super.init(questionText: questionText)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great advice! Thanks for catching some of my mistakes. I appreciate your input!

Comment: @TannerDanger if I answered your question please accept the answer, it is the green checkmark

Answer (score 1):

One solution to your question about casting is the following:

```
if let question = question as? TextResponseQuestion {
    question.responseText = responseText
}
```

That being said, I'd reconsider your architecture if I were in your position, for a couple of reasons:

1. You're using classes for your model -- SwiftUI `@State` variables will work better with value types vs reference types. `struct`s will be more likely to be what you're looking for.
2. You're trying to store the answers along with the questions -- I'd consider splitting up the answers into a separate store
3. Assuming that you did #2, you could use enums with associated values instead of different subclasses for the different types of questions. In fact, you could do that even without #2, but I think separating the questions and answers may be cleaner.

Comment: That solves my down casting question! Thanks for helping me understand. I'll try out a different architecture model.